# Neo4j Javascript Driver Server keeps Expiring Session

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, websocket

I've tried the following in node 7.3.0, 7.3.1 and 8.0.1:

```
import * as v1 from 'neo4j-driver';

const neo4j = v1.v1;
const auth = neo4j.auth.basic( 'neo4j', 'password' );
console.log( 'auth.basic returned: ' + JSON.stringify( auth ));
const driver = neo4j.driver( 'bolt://localhost', auth );
const session = driver.session();

const query = `
    CREATE (string:TEST:Type {name: 'String'})
    CREATE (int:TEST:Type {name: 'Int'})
    CREATE (id:TEST:Type {name: 'ID'})
    CREATE (query:TEST:Type {name: 'Query'})
    CREATE (mutation:TEST:Type {name: 'Mutation'})
    CREATE (subscription:TEST:Type {name: 'Subscription'})
    CREATE (author:TEST:Type {name: 'Author'})
    CREATE (post:TEST:Type {name: 'Post'})
    CREATE (comment:TEST:Type {name: 'Comment'})
`

session.run( { statements: query } )
    .then( ( result ) => {
        console.log( result );
    } )
    .catch( ( err ) => { console.log( err ); } );
```

That gives me (with debug on):

```
auth.basic returned: {"scheme":"basic","principal":"neo4j","credentials":"password"}
C:INIT "neo4j-javascript/0.0.0-dev" {"scheme":"basic","principal":"neo4j","credentials":"password"}
S:SUCCESS {"server":"Neo4j/3.1.0"}
C:RUN {"statements":"\n\tCREATE (string:TEST:Type {name: 'String'})\n\tCREATE (int:TEST:Type {name: 'Int'})\n\tCREATE (id:TEST:Type {name: 'ID'})\n\t
CREATE (query:TEST:Type {name: 'Query'})\n\tCREATE (mutation:TEST:Type {name: 'Mutation'})\n\tCREATE (subscription:TEST:Type {name: 'Subscription'})\
n\tCREATE (author:TEST:Type {name: 'Author'})"} {}
C:PULL_ALL
{ Error: Connection was closed by server
    at new Neo4jError (/Users/timhope/Dev/ts-koapollo/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/error.js:65:132)
    at newError (/Users/timhope/Dev/ts-koapollo/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/error.js:55:10)
    at NodeChannel._handleConnectionTerminated (/Users/timhope/Dev/ts-koapollo/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/ch-node.js:330:41)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) code: 'SessionExpired' }
```

I thought maybe it was a bolt or server-side problem so I tried cypher-shell.

Same query through cypher-shell:

```
bash-3.2$ ./neo4j-community-3.1.0/bin/cypher-shell
username: neo4j
password: ********
Connected to Neo4j 3.1.0 at bolt://localhost:7687 as user neo4j.
Type :help for a list of available commands or :exit to exit the shell.
Note that Cypher queries must end with a semicolon.
neo4j> :help

Available commands:
  :begin    Open a transaction
  :commit   Commit the currently open transaction
  :exit     Exit the logger
  :help     Show this help message
  :history  Print a list of the last commands executed
  :param    Set the value of a query parameter
  :params   Prints all currently set query parameters and their values
  :rollback Rollback the currently open transaction

For help on a specific command type:
    :help command


For help on cypher please visit:
    https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1-beta/cypher/

neo4j> CREATE (string:TEST:Type {name: 'String'})
       CREATE (int:TEST:Type {name: 'Int'})
       CREATE (id:TEST:Type {name: 'ID'})
       CREATE (query:TEST:Type {name: 'Query'})
       CREATE (mutation:TEST:Type {name: 'Mutation'})
       CREATE (subscription:TEST:Type {name: 'Subscription'});
Added 9 nodes
```

I'm absolutely stumped, any help is much appreciated. I'm going mad. I've tried a million variations of starting and closing sessions and drivers to no avail.

Comment: did you solve the problem? I am having same problem, don't know what to do :(

Comment: @alim It turned out to be a combination of things we resolved it on github eventually. Here's a link: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/issues/187

Hopefully something in there helps.

The main problem turned out to be passing an object into `session.run` a syntax which I'd carried over from another library. `session.run` expects a string.

Comment: @ the solution says use ' query' in session.run, right? I tried and still having problem. i posted my question, could you take a look at it please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990605/how-to-fix-connection-was-closed-by-sever-in-nodejs-neo4j

Comment: We are getting plagued by this problem right now also in both our Frontend apps. After much analysis, we contacted Neo4j yesterday (on May 27, 2017) and they said they are aware of the problem but no release date yet.

Oddly enough, I was just Googling to download the Neo4j driver for a CRONjob and I saw this result, so I figured I would let everyone know.

Comment: I think it's still not resolved.