# how to fix "connection was closed by sever" in nodejs +neo4j?

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I could not run the very simple program, as shown below

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:port", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
var session = driver.session(); 

session.run(` MATCH (a) return a `)
       .then(s => {
            console.log('success');
            session.close();
            driver.close();
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('errororororor', err);
            session.close();
            driver.close();
        });
```

for the "port", I tried 7687 or just "bolt://localhost", none worked.

driver.OnError(log(error)), printed the following

> Driver instantiation failed Structure {
>    signature: 127,
>    fields: 
>     [ { code: 'Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized',
>         message: 'The client is unauthorized due to authentication >failure.' } ] }

How can I fix it, please help!

Comment: the problem is most likely the **server**

Comment: @JaromandaX could you be more specific? what should I do?

Comment: it could be anything on the server ... the code ... firewall ... mutant ant overlords

Comment: What, if any error logs are you getting? And which callback is getting called? `.then` or `.catch`?

Comment: @JaromandaX any suggestion to fix if there is a problem with server?

Comment: What version of node/neo4j are you running?

Comment: @ node is v7.6.0, neo4j is 3.1.2.

Comment: Are you sure you've got you auth details right because your code works for me on those versions. Try registering a callback with `driver.onError(err => {console.log(err)})`

Comment: @TimHope you are right, something wrong with my auth, i put the error message above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138883/discussion-between-tim-hope-and-alim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you haven't finished setting up your neo4j server. If you've not just used 'neo4j' as a dummy password.

Neo4j won't allow you to connect via bolt until you've set a password. to do this you can either log into the browser interface at http://localhost:7474 enter the default username and password and you'll be prompted for a new one.

or if you're using a command line installation you can also run `neo4j-admin set-initial-password [password]`.

Hope that helps. (If you need more help send me a message in the chat I started from the comments on the question.)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but not for localhost DB (GrapheneDB instance), I fixed it by adding a config like that :

```
var driver = neo4j.driver("BOLTURL:PORT", neo4j.auth.basic("USR", "PWS"),**{ encrypted : true}**);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: you never had the issue again? We do have the issue with a neo4j Aura instance. It happens sometime without knowing the issue. It doesn't come directly from one query as we can restart our node server and rerun the same query with no problem.